# European soccer championship: Where can I find historic data on the market value of the teams

Tags: data

I want to write a simple model predicting the performance of the teams in the european soccer championship. The results of soccer matches are known to be strongly correlated with the market value of the teams. The idea is to include in the model only data on the market value of the team and its players, to train it on historical data and see how good this very simple approach can be.

Where can I find historic data on the market value of the teams and its players? I found data on the championships 2016 and 2020, but not further back.

Answer (score 0):

Worth to check:

https://fivethirtyeight.com/methodology/how-our-club-soccer-predictions-work/

Data sources for soccer prediction:

https://www.transfermarkt.com/

https://github.com/jalapic/engsoccerdata

Useful resource:

https://dev.to/lisandramelo/extracting-data-from-transfermarkt-an-introduction-to-webscraping-2i1c